# Clamp angle between two vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm programming a snake-type game in 3 dimensions without grid constraints where the location of the new 'block' is determined by:

> [Normalized(lastBlockLocation - cursorLocation) * blockLength] + lastBlockLocation

where locations are 3D vectors and blockLength is an scalar. With this code, I make the snake follow the player without caring of the actual distance; however, I would also like to add a system to avoid too sharp angles.

So, here's the question: how can I clamp a vector so it has a maximun angle n with a know vector?

Comment: Which angle are you trying to clamp?

Comment: The one between the known vector and the new vector; I want to clamp the vector itself.

Comment: The “known vector” being `lastBlockLocation`?

Comment: No, the know vector is the forward vector of the last block added - the direction the snake would advance if the player didn't move the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the angle $\beta$ by which the snake changes its heading to be capped at some fixed angle $\beta_\text{max}$. I would separate detection from setting the new heading.

Let $\mathbf u$ be a unit vector pointing in the current direction and $\mathbf u_\text{cursor}={\mathbf r_\text{cursor}-\mathbf r\over\|\mathbf r_\text{cursor}-\mathbf r\|}$ a unit vector in the direction of the cursor relative to the last block location. Then the change in direction is too large if $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf u_\text{cursor}=\cos\beta\lt\cos{\beta_\text{max}}$.

If the change in angle is small enough, proceed as before. If not, you need to rotate $\mathbf u$ by $\beta_\text{max}$ toward the cursor. There are several ways to do this, but I think the following is one of the more efficient. Compute the orthogonal rejection $\mathbf v_\perp=\mathbf u_\text{cursor}-(\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf u_\text{cursor})\mathbf u$. You’ve already got this dot product from the previous step. Then, the clamped new direction will be given by the unit vector $$\mathbf u_\text{clamped}=\cos\beta_\text{max}\mathbf u+\sin\beta_\text{max}{\mathbf v_\perp\over\|\mathbf v_\perp\|}.$$ The sine and cosine of $\beta_\text{max}$ can of course be precomputed.

The case $\mathbf u_\text{cursor}=-\mathbf u$, i.e., the cursor is directly behind the snake, will need special handling. You’ll need to pick a direction—clockwise or counterclockwise—and a plane for the change in heading. [*Addition*] One possibility is to save the most recent previous heading $\mathbf u_\text{prev}\ne\mathbf u$ and use $-\mathbf u_\text{prev}$ instead of $\mathbf u_\text{cursor}$ to compute the clamped direction change in this case. That will turn the snake in a manner consistent with its most recent direction change.

Comment: Did you mean to say `orthogonal projection` and not `orthogonal rejection`? I can't find anything on Google of such a measure. Also, is there a name for this method of rotation that you specified, is this a rotor or...? In my mind I see you getting the orthogonal vector to u and then just using trig solve for a point on a circle in the plane both vectors lie on.

Comment: @Coburn That’s a good way to visualize what’s going on. Another way to look at it is that $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v_\perp/\|\mathbf v_\perp\|$ form an orthonormal basis for the plane defined by $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$, so the coefficients are just the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the max rotation vector.

Comment: @Coburn Orthogonal *rejection* is correct. That’s the component left over after subtracting the orthogonal projection. It’s what’s computed over and over in the Gram-Schmidt process, for instance. It will, of course, be orthogonal to the vector onto which you’re projecting. Here’s the top hit in my Google search for the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection .

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it that isn't that mathematical, but it gives pretty nice results. Instead of checking if the change in direction is too big, I simply lerp between my current direction and the target direction with this formula:

Direction = (TargetDirection - Direction) / Speed

To see this formula in action, refer to http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/11/13/snippets-i-always-forget-movement/ (the Move Towards an Object With Easing)

This not only prevents the snake from turning too much or too fast; it also makes the motion much more fluid and nice

Comment: Interesting idea, but unless the snake happens to be heading directly toward the target in the first place, it’ll never reach it (up to the limits of position resolution, that is). Perhaps there’s more to this than you’ve described here.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this after realizing it looked way better when the snake didn't reach the destination. Instead, it orbits :)